# Disjoint exceptional lines on non-minimal cubic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, cubics

A diagonal cubic surface $\sum_{i=0}^3a_iT_i^3=0$ is not minimal if, for example, $a_1a_2a_3^{-1}a_4^{-1}\in(k^*)^3$. This should be because there is an exceptional line $D$ such that no element in the Galois group takes $D$ to a distinct exceptional line $D'$ and $D\cap D'\neq \emptyset$. I can't get my head around how to find which lines are these, corresponding to say $a_1a_2a_3^{-1}a_4^{-1}\in(k^*)^3$?

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this characterization - if you set all the coefficients to 1, the condition is satisfied, and that's the Fermat cubic which has exactly 27 lines.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, let me clarify this: 1) $k$ is not algebraically closed. 2) Among the 27 lines, there will be some line(s) $D$ such that you cannot find a Galois element with the above conditions. For the example you gave, the line given by the pair of equations $T_0+T_1=0$, $T_2+T_3=0$ is such a line. In general, the 27 lines are given by the pairs of the form $a_0^{1/3}T_0+\theta^k a_1^{1/3}T_1=0$, $a_2^{1/3}T_2+\theta^l a_3^{1/3}T_3=0$ , $l$, $k$ from 0 to 2. This gives 9, and grouping $T_0$ with $T_2$, $T_3$ give the others.

Comment: @KReiser Embarrassingly I remember this should be a rather easy problem, and I did this some time ago. But today when I needed this again I suddenly cannot get my head around and recall what was the arithmetic/trick I did...